# creating multiple lists and use them in a loop

Tags: python, list, loops

I want to write a function that creates multiple empty lists, based on the given parameter like that:

```
for i in range(parameter):
    list_i = []
```

Then I want to loop through another given list and if I encounter the number 2 for example I want it to be added to list_2.
Currently I'm trying this here:

```
if i in cluster_i:
   cluster_i.append(...)
```

But that doesn't seem to work as it should.
Does anyone have a solution for that problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is not recommended. Instead, use a dict as following:

```py
lists = {}
for i in range(parameter):
    lists.setdefault(i, [])
```